# How to get Epoch calculation in Java from SQL query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, servlets

I was working on a query where there are two columns from different databases that store date with timestamp. Later I am running the following query to get the total hours in integer.

```
SELECT tab1.col1,
tab1.date1 as d1, tab2.date2 as d2,
(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM tab2.date2 - tab1.date1)/3600)::integer as delta
FROM table1 tab1 left join table2 tab2 on tab1.col1=tab2.col1;
```

Where,

```
date1 have following value= "2014-03-22 22:00:00.022023"
and date2 = "2014-03-26 16:45:04.445531"
```

When the above query runs it gives back this as `delta` =91 hour

I needed to carry this calculation using Java,

So far what have I done:

```
    String sql3 = " Select col1, date1 from table2 where col1 =?";
    for (QueryResponse resp : response) {

        statement3 = connection3.prepareStatement(sql3);
        statement3.setString(1, resp.getCol1());        
        Timestamp queryDate = resp.getqDate();

        // execute select SQL stetement

        ResultSet rs3 = statement3.executeQuery();

        while (rs3.next()) {
            String col = rs3.getString("col1");
            Timestamp createdDate = rs3.getTimestamp("date1");
            int delta = 48; // Not sure how to calculate
            resp.setDelta(delta);
        }
```

Similarly I have date2 from table1 in a `response`

I wanted to carry out the same

> `(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM tab2.date2 - tab1.date1)/3600)::integer as
>   delta`

in the block where `int delta = 48` is written in java?

Any help on this would be great, I am not sure how to transform it in Java the `Epoch` functionality

Comment: Are you trying to get the time elapsed since `epoch` (of Java) using SQL code ?

Comment: Try this - `declare @epoch datetime = '1970-01-01'
declare @today datetime = getdate()
select datediff(hh,@epoch,@today) as Delta_hh`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, Thanks! I am trying to transform the SQLQuery that helped me get the difference between two dates and conversion of result in hours in java code. As I have mentioned, I created a statement to get those two columns from different table and saved it in `response` all I need is to set the delta value after I have calculated the delta hour? Hope I did not made it too complex